# SSL Proxy via NGINX for Websockets cannot establish a connection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nginx, websocket

I am hosting a game server (Websocket-sharp + Unity Headless) on a linux server with NGINX as a proxy.

NGINX configuration

```
server {
    
    server_name game.okdev.se; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5009;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwarded_For $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect default;
        client_max_body_size 1000m; 
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/game.okdev.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/game.okdev.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Server C# code
I'm not using SSL with C# but rather the SSL part should be handled by NGINX, this exact setup has worked for previous
projects using NodeJS and Websockets. The only path for my Websocket server is /

```
wssv = new WebSocketServer(port);
wssv.AddWebSocketService("/", () => new SocketInstance(this));
```

Unity Client C# code
Connecting via NGINX and SSL does not work at all.

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://game.okdev.se/");
```

Connecting with the Unity client to the direct (port forwarded) port, without SSL and bypassing NGINX works.

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://game.okdev.se:5009/");
```

Comment: Hello, are you still getting this issue? I also got this issue with nginx and websocket sharp. Is there any solution yet for this question?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing
`proxy_http_version 1.1;`

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I had it in the configuration before but accidentally removed it when testing. I will keep it in the configuration.